# How do i uniquely print out the elements of a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

I want to know how i can uniquely print out the elements of each list inside the dictionary without printing duplicates. Sorry i am quite new to programming. I am reading Python Crash Course 2nd edition and want to add a little bit of a challenge to my code.

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': ['python', 'c'],
    'mark': ['c'],
    'tom': ['ruby', 'haskell'],
    'amy': ['python', 'ruby'],
}

print("Mentioned languages:")

for languages in favorite_languages.values(): # Loop over the dictionaries unique values only
    if len(languages) !=  1:
        languages = set(tuple(languages))
        for language in languages:
            print("\t",language.title())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the lists in favorite_languages.values() by adding them to a blank list, and taking the set at the end:

```
print("Mentioned languages:")

languages = []
for language in favorite_languages.values():
    languages += language

languages = set(languages)

for language in languages:
    print("\t",language.title())
```

You'll see in PCC that you can combine some of these lines, but for the sake of clarity I've put each step on a different line.